# Where should I close the File Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am trying to get the text of a file in C# (config) and to put it into fields. The code itself works, but I need to close the file stream to open a new one futher in the code, but don't know where to put the Close() tag. Can someone help me?

```
string documentspath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string rpath = documentspath + @"\Luminous\remember.ini";
if (File.Exists(rpath))
{
    try
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(rpath);
        string path = text.Split('|')[0];
        string process = text.Split('|')[1];

        string loadLib = text.Split('|')[2];

        pathBox.Text = path;
        processBox.Text = process;
        if (loadLib == "True")
        {
            loadLibrary.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            manualMap.Checked = true;
        }
    } catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Config file corrupted. Remembered data has been lost and deleted.");
        File.Delete(rpath);
    }
} else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No config file loaded. Welcome, " + Environment.UserName + ".");
}
```

EDIT: Here's the code from where I'm opening another file stream.

```
string documentspath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (!Directory.Exists(documentspath + @"\Luminous")) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(documentspath + @"\Luminous");
} else {
    string rpath = documentspath + @"\Luminous\remember.ini";
    if (!File.Exists(rpath)) {
        File.Create(rpath);
        File.WriteAllText(rpath, pathBox.Text + "|" + processBox.Text + "|" + loadlibcheck + "|" + manualmapcheck);
    } else {
            File.WriteAllText(rpath, string.Empty);
            File.WriteAllText(rpath, pathBox.Text + "|" + processBox.Text + "|" + loadlibcheck + "|" + manualmapcheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in his code is a a file stream? I see a static method of File pulling all in one go. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I didn't notice that I there was no file stream in the first code block. Sorry for that.

Comment: Please remove all the needless whitespace from your code. I fixed it the first time, you overwrote it. Thanks.

Comment: Why bother calling `Create` when `WriteAllText` will do that automatically?  Just remove that line of code.  In fact, you can remove the `if` block altogether and just call `WriteAllText`.  From the docs for `WriteAllText`:  _Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error appears because of this line:

```
File.Create(rpath);
```

Try:

```
using(File.Create(rpath)) {}
```

`File.Create` method actually return `FileStream`, which have to be disposed. Some info about it can be found on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx).

In section "Return Value":

> Type: System.IO.FileStream A FileStream that provides read/write
>   access to the file specified in path.

In section "Remarks":

> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.

However, as [Chris Dunaway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70104/chris-dunaway) mentioned, there is no need to use `File.Create` at all, as according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) `WriteAllText` :

> Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Comment: nice one Alex! sharp eye! Now if you include the line from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) which shows that `Create` actually returns a `FileStream` and post the remark that says, that "no other process can use this file until the stream is closed" you answer would be sound and round

Comment: worked, didn't notice that. gonna select it as accepted in a sec.

Comment: excellent! Has everything that a good answer needs :) Identification of problem, backed up by information from the documentation and a solution for the problem! I would vote up again, if I could ;)

Comment: Why bother calling `Create` when `WriteAllText` will do that automatically?  Just remove that line of code.  In fact, you can remove the `if` block altogether and just call `WriteAllText`.  From the docs for `WriteAllText`:  _Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten._

Comment: Sure go ahead.  It could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to close `File` when using `File.ReadAllText()`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx):

> File.ReadAllText Method Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file.

Comment: I need to close it, since I am writing text in the same file further in the code and I get an error that says that the file is already used by another process. Tried some things and doing that, I noticed that its cause of the code I provided. (doesn't close)

Comment: @biss: sure that the error is not raised in the code which you have shown, but actually is caused by a not closed file-stream in other code which you haven't shown?

Comment: Yes. I am totally sure since without the code from the first block, it works. (Its a remember function)

Answer (score 3):

You have two good options:

1. On the `finally` clause of your `try/catch` block.
2. Change your code to use `using` statement for your file stream.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close anything. `File.ReadAllText` reads and closes a stream internally. So you can safely invoke another `File.ReadAllText` if you need to.